# Jquery - How to find a #tag a name and apply a class

Tags: jquery

When on #page1 of a website I'd like the menu item for #page1 to be highlighted like a current page style. I've tried add a class and applying css directly with the code below, neither works.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? THANKS in advance.

```
var url = window.location.href;
if (url.search("#page1") > 0) {
$("#mainNav ul li a.scroll1").addClass("current");
$("#mainNav ul li a.scroll1").css("color","#000");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you should just be able to search `window.location.hash` and use that as a selector. For instance, if you're on `http://localhost/index.php#page1`, the hash value returned from the window object will be `#page1`. You could use that to lookup your element:

```
// Reference to hash, or empty string
var page = window.location.hash;

// If the resulting string isn't empty
if ( page.length ) {
    // Target the corresponding element, add a class
    $( "a." + page.slice(1).replace(/page/,'scroll') ).addClass( "selected" );
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, I have 4 # anames setup, #page1, #page2, #page3, #page4. Page 1 is associated with the menu item a.scroll1, Page 2 - a.scroll2 etc. I don't understand how to use your code above in this circumstance?

Comment: @user1770137 That requires removing the `#` and replacing "page" with the word "scroll". I believe the updates above should take care of that.

Answer (score 0):

After this question I worked out a very simple solution to this question. The code below creates a Current Page class on an LI when clicked, and removes all other current page classes from other Menu LI's at the same time.

HTML

```
<ul>
<li class="scrollButton1 current"><a href="#page1">Welcome</a></li>
<li class="scrollButton2"><a href="#page2">Education</a></li>
<li class="scrollButton3"><a href="#page3">Triathlon</a></li>
<li class="scrollButton4"><a href="#page4">Register</a></li>
</ul>
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.scrollButton1').click(function(){$('html, body').removeClass('current'), $('#mainNav ul li.scrollButton1').addClass('current');});
$('.scrollButton2').click(function(){$('html, body').removeClass('current'), $('#mainNav ul li.scrollButton2').addClass('current');});
$('.scrollButton3').click(function(){$('html, body').removeClass('current'), $('#mainNav ul li.scrollButton3').addClass('current');});
$('.scrollButton4').click(function(){$('html, body').removeClass('current'), $('#mainNav ul li.scrollButton4').addClass('current');});
});
```

Hope this helps.